# Webpack copy plugin transform does not transform

Tags: vue.js, webpack

In Vue3, I am using webpack from a `vue.config.js` chainWebpack. I am trying to tap into a single file and transform that during the copy.

```
module.exports = {  
    publicPath: './',
    chainWebpack: config => {
        
        // tell webpack this is a regular file,
        // otherwise if will fail anyway
        config.module
            .rule('webmanifest')
            .test(/site\.webmanifest$/)
            .type('asset/resource')
            
        // on the copy plugin, add a pattern to transform it
        config.plugin('copy').tap(([options]) => {
            options.patterns.push(
                {
                    from: 'public/site.webmanifest',
                    to: 'dist/site.webmanifest',
                    transform: buffer => {
                        console.log('you are here');
                        return 'I HAVE REWRITTEN YOUR MANIFEST'
                    }
                }
            );
            return [options]
        })
    }
}
```

It does log 'you are here'. But the file contents remain the same in the output.

There are no errors. Am I expecting something wrong ?
Or can I not add transformers with a 'tap' here ?

Answer (score 0):

It works now, and I *think* this is what did it:

```
module.exports = {  
    publicPath: './',
    chainWebpack: config => {
        
        // tell webpack this is a regular file,
        // and use the verbose filename everywhere
        // where it is mentioned, but *do not output the file*
        // the copy plugin will transform and output this later.
        config.module
            .rule('webmanifest')
            .test(/site\.webmanifest$/)
            .type('asset/resource')
            .set('generator', {
                filename: "site.webmanifest",
                emit: false 
            });
            
        // on the copy plugin, add a pattern to transform it
        config.plugin('copy').tap(([options]) => {
            options.patterns.push(
                {
                    from: 'public/site.webmanifest',
                    to: 'site.webmanifest', // notice dist is missing here
                    transform: buffer => {
                        console.log('you are here');
                        return 'I HAVE REWRITTEN YOUR MANIFEST'
                    }
                }
            );
            return [options]
        })
    }
}
```

Obviously, that transformer is a test. It should do something like
`return buffer.toString().replace('foo','bar');`